# Using a recursive bisection search to check if a character is in a string

Tags: python, search, bisection, edx

My code is here:

```
def isIn(char, aStr):
mid = len(aStr)//2
if len(aStr)==0:
    return False
elif len(aStr)==1:
    if char == aStr:
        return True
elif aStr[mid] == char:
    return True
if mid == 0 and len(aStr) != 1:
    return False
else:
    if char > aStr[mid]:
        return isIn(char,aStr[mid:] )
    else:
        return isIn(char,aStr[0:mid])
```

my code works for when the character is present in the string, if the test case is such that if the character that I want to search in the string is not actually present in the string, then the code goes into an infinite loop.
For example in the test case **isIn('m','iloruuyz')** the code goes into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

On the `if len(aStr) == 1:` condition, you only return True if the condition is met, but not `False` if the condition is not, that is where the infinite loop is occuring :)

```
def isIn(char, aStr):
    mid = len(aStr)//2
    if len(aStr)==0:
        return False
    elif len(aStr)==1:
        if char == aStr:
            return True
        else: # Else return false to stop the infinite loop
            return False
    elif aStr[mid] == char:
        return True
    if mid == 0 and len(aStr) != 1:
        return False
    else:
        if char > aStr[mid]:
            return isIn(char,aStr[mid:] )
        else:
            return isIn(char,aStr[0:mid])
```